# What is the most appropriate tool to automate Sharepoint application?

Tags: automated-testing

I am trying to automate Sharepoint. Firstly to start with the basic features, further my sites, site collections and so on. Can anyone suggest a good tool to automate system tests for Sharepoint since it is using Microsoft Silverlight?

Answer (score 4):

Since it is web based, if you are looking for perform functional testing at the UI level there are a couple of tools you might take a look at:

1. Telerik Test Studio (the underlying WebAII test framework is free).  We are using this currently at my company.
2. http://www.ranorex.com/ - another tool very similar
3. You may also be able to combine [WatiN](http://watin.org/) and [White](http://white.codeplex.com/)

Selenium may also be able to get you there but I am not clear on what support it has or has been written as an add on for Silverlight.